# Loop error 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

I put in the following python code and can't figure out why I am getting an error. The loop runs fine, but the 'preds' keeps getting the error and points to the loop being the issue.

```
def predict(pred_prob,threshold):
    pred = []  
    for i in range(len(pred_prob)):
        if list[i] >= threshold: 
            pred.append(1) 
        else:
            pred.append(0)
    return pred



probs = [0.174,0.817,0.574,0.319,0.812,0.314,0.098,0.741,0.847,
         0.202,0.31,0.073,0.179,]
thresh = 0.55
preds = predict(probs, thresh)
```

Why do I keep getting the following error "'type' object is not subscriptable"?

Comment: What were you expecting `list[i]` to do?  That's something you'd do with a particular list object (`pred_prob`, most likely), *not* the `list` type itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have tried to index `list`, which is a Python type, not an actual list. In your problem, your actual list is called `pred_prob`, so your predict function should rather be:

```
def predict(pred_prob, threshold):
    pred = []
    for i in range(len(pred_prob)):
        if pred_prob[i] >= threshold:
            pred.append(1)
        else:
            pred.append(0)
    return pred
```

By the way, a more Pythonistic way of generating this result would be to use a comprehension, for example:

```
preds = [int(p >= thresh) for p in probs]
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 4, `list` is a python type. You can't "get elements" from a type, because it is not iterable. I think you want to put `pred_prob[i]` instead of `list[i]`